# Enum Issue for same ID and different description

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, enums

I am facing issue with Enum's in C#.

I have `enum` data with same id but different descriptions.

```
public enum Flags
{
    [Description("Flag Yes")]
    FlagYes=1,
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo=1,
    [Description("Item Yes")]
    ItemYes=2,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo=2,
}

Flags flag = Flags.FlagYes;
string Description = flag.Description();
```

I got inside `Description` value "Flag No" but i need "Flag Yes". Any on help me how it fix it this one?

I Used below common code for getting description from `enum`.

```
public static string Description(this Enum Value)
{
    FieldInfo field = Value.GetType().GetField(Value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
    return attribute == null ? Value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
}
```

Any solution please let me know?

Comment: What about fixing your enum to have different values for all options?

Comment: @Evk, 
 I need solution for getting "Flag Yes" description from the enum scenario.

Comment: Well you cannot do that, because enum is just a number internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said what you are currently doing is not possible, you cannot have two flags with the same integer value and then try and distinguish between them

An alternative is to change you enum to having additional values for grouping other values together:

```
public enum Flags
{
    [Description("Flag Yes")]
    FlagYes = 1,
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo = 2,
    [Description("Item Yes")]
    ItemYes = 4,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo = 8,
    IsFlag = (FlagYes | FlagNo), //group Flag values 
    IsItem = (ItemYes | ItemNo)  //group Item values
}
```

You can then check if the enum is a Flag or Item like this:

```
public bool IsFlag(Flags a)
{
    return (Flags.IsFlag.HasFlag(a));
}

public bool IsItem(Flags a)
{
    return (Flags.IsFlag.HasFlag(a));
}
```

**Update**

As others have explained the underlying type of an Enum is the int value. So even though in your code you are saying `FlagYes` it is the value 1 that is passed the method. Your code then looks up value 1 and finds `FlagsNo`. 
The number 1 cannot mean both `FlagsYes` and `FlagNo`.

If you need your enum to be the value 1 and 2 but also need FlagsYes and FlagsNo you have two seperate concerns and need to create a different solution.

If the value for `FlagsYes` and `FlagsNo` is arbitrary and can anything as long as they are the same then you create the group enum values as per the above code.

Comment: No need same ID in the enum.

Comment: because i use some filter calculation, so its need same id for flag type Yes/No and Item Yes/No

Comment: What do mean my some filter calculation Do they have to be the same or do they have to be 1 & 2? It sounds like you want the Flags enum to serve two different needs. Without more context of how you want to use the enum I am not sure how anyone can help.

Comment: Yes, like 1 & 2

Comment: exactly in my project i use more then 100 Enum  property. i need to group the propery, for example 1 is one group, and 2 is another group. in this group i am not able to get my exact description. this is my issue. but i use exact Enumproperty in my code(example: FlagYes but its give "Flag No" description automatcally its give last Enumproperty description)

Comment: I have updated my answer...does FlagYes & FlagsNo have to be 1 or do they just have to be the same?

Comment: Please note the enum values goes up in by the power of 2 (1,2,4,8,16...)

Comment: Thank your thinking, i tried but not use, more then 25 group in some enum.

Comment: I don't the number of enums in the group should matter unless enums can be part of multiple groups. How did this impact your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have 4 values in the `enum` but only two "real" values.
So your posted `enum` in the question is actually more likely equal to this:

```
public enum Flags
{
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo=1,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo=2,
}
```

with the ability to access `FlagNo` and `ItemNo` using `FlagYes` and `ItemYes` because they are also defined, but with same value.

In order to solve your problem you have to fix your `enum` to look like this:

```
public enum Flags
{
    [Description("Flag Yes")]
    FlagYes=1,
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo=2,
    [Description("Item Yes")]
    ItemYes=3,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo=4,
```

}

**Edit according to comments:**

> I got "Flag No" but i need "Flag Yes". Any on help me how it fix it this one?

To reply to your comment, if you have a really strong reason why do you want to have same ID, I suggest as well having two `enum`, one for the *yes* and one for the *no*, the way you have used it:

```
Flags flag = Flags.FlagYes;
string Description = flag.Description();
```

won't let the 'code' to magically know which description to give you, so if you want, here's another way to do it having same ID with two `enum`:

```
public enum YesFlags
{
    [Description("Flag Yes")]
    FlagYes=1,
    [Description("Item Yes")]
    ItemYes=2
}

public enum NoFlags
{
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo=1,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo=2
}
```

Then you can use the required `enum` with same ID.

Comment: @NeoVijay Then you are using enums the wrong way. google for some tutorials and comparisons for enum vs. class vs. struct

Comment: @NeoVijay The default underlying data type for an `enum` in `C#` is an int, so what you really want is nearly impossible or just impossible. You can't have same `id` for both, consider it as a unique primary key in database where you can't have duplicate keys. `enum` is to `enumerate`. If you have a really strong reason to have same ID, I either suggest using two `enum`, or just not use `enum` at all.

Comment: @PaulKaram: Please refer my  comment "exactly in my project...", 
Address : Scrobi 5th comment

Comment: @NeoVijay As we said, `enum` default underlying data type is int, so when you're requesting `Flags.FlagYes;` You're asking to get the description from this `enum` where value is equal to `1` which will be the `flagno` description because you assigned the value 1 to it after the `flagyes`. You can't use same value in same `enum` for two different items and expect to get the results you're seeking.

Comment: @NeoVijay please check the updated answer at the start, more explanation of what I mean

Comment: I understand,but i need to group the enum, i will try some other way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what do you mean by grouping the enum? Maybe we can also help when everything is more clear

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. Since you have both assigned 1 to both enum entries, there is no way to distinguish between them, because internally, only the numeric values are taken into consideration.

Comment: Thank you, i except yes or no.

Comment: But its compile well. and its could not any error on runtime. and also give wrong return

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration in .NET is basically an integer where the compiler helps you to ensure that it is only one of a previously selected range of constants. Because enums are value types, only the underlying number is present at runtime. There is no extra field that specifies which of the constants is meant because this is supposed to be encoded in that number.

Being numbers, however, you have all integer operations at your disposal for enumerations and that includes bitwise operations. You may have come across the `|` operator to combine flagged enums, but you can also use masks:

```
public enum Flags
{
    [Description("Flag Yes")]
    FlagYes=1,
    [Description("Flag No")]
    FlagNo=5,
    [Description("Item Yes")]
    ItemYes=2,
    [Description("Item No")]
    ItemNo=6,
    Mask=3
}
```

Then, you can restore your id using `value & Flags.Mask`. However, `ItemNo` and `FlagNo` can still be distinguished.